# Confuse with `: Something` After abstract function declaration

Tags: php, oop

I am just exploring one GitHub repo and comes with a doubt that I not able to find out in google.

I know we can only define an abstract function. but here with this code

```
namespace DesignPatterns\Creational\AbstractFactory;
/**
 * In this case, the abstract factory is a contract for creating some components
 * for the web. There are two ways of rendering text: HTML and JSON
 */
abstract class AbstractFactory
{
    abstract public function createText(string $content): Text;
}
```

They have putted :Text behind function. I Checked and found Text is an another abstract class they have defined inside the repo.
what it mean here? I am not getting what it mean by `: Text` After abstract function declaration.

Comment: I am checking the code here on popular repo for PHP design pattern.

https://github.com/domnikl/DesignPatternsPHP/blob/master/Creational/AbstractFactory/AbstractFactory.php#L11

Comment: It's the return type of the function.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [a new feature for PHP 7](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php) called a "Return Type Declaration" or "Return Hinting". Here is the RFC: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/return_types

Here is some example code from the RFC:

```
interface A {
    static function make(): A;
}
class B implements A {
    static function make(): A {
        return new B();
    }
}
```

In your case, it is saying that the abstract method `createText`, when implemented, needs to return an instance of the `Text` class.

See also: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.returning-values.php

Comment: It's interesting, Now I can proceed my exploration ahead :D